# Bison using %define api.pure full wihout a %union but C++ variants instead

Tags: compiler-construction, bison, yacc, bisonc++

I have a hand-written scanner and a bison parser which can parse this sentence (made it short for the question context):

```
var x : integer
```

Bison:

```
%require "3.2"
%define api.pure full


%code{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "Scanner.h"
#include<iostream>
}



%code{
    int yylex(YYSTYPE *lvalp);
    #include<iostream>
    #include<string>
    Scanner scanner;
    void yyerror(const char *error);
}


%union {
int n;
double d;
char s[1000];
}

%token VAR COL ITYPE
%token IDENTIFIER
%token INTEGER
%token EOL

%type <s> type PrimitiveType IDENTIFIER
%type <s> INTEGER    

%%
program:
| program EOL
| program SimpleDeclaration {  }
;

SimpleDeclaration: VariableDeclaration
;

VariableDeclaration: VAR IDENTIFIER COL type {std::cout<<"defined variable " << $2 << " with type " << $4 << std::endl; }

type: IDENTIFIER
| PrimitiveType
;

PrimitiveType: ITYPE { strcpy($$, "int"); }
;

%%
int main()
{
    scanner.set_file("inp.txt");
    return yyparse();
}

void yyerror(const char *error)
{
    std::cout << "syntax error" << std::endl;
}

int yylex(YYSTYPE *lvalp)
{
    return scanner.get_next_token(lvalp);
}
```

`scanner.get_next_token(lvalp)` returns a token `INTEGER` for example (included parser.tab.hpp in `scanner.cpp` and making use of the generated enums from the tokens). Also, before that it puts the correct value in `lvalp` such as `strcpy(lvalp->s, nextTokenString.c_str())` and `lvalp->n = toInt(nextTokenString)` and so on....
The output is:

```
defined variable x with type int
```

but I want to use STL containers and smart pointers. In [this page about pure calling](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Pure-Calling.html), it is not told how to use `lvalp*` wihout a union if your tokens are not the same type. In addition, according to [this page](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/C_002b_002b-Variants.html) I should put `%language "c++"` in addition to `%define api.value.type variant` to use C++ variants which accept semantic types instead of `union`. Well, that results in the following error:

`parser.ypp:3.1-21: error: %define variable 'api.pure' is not used`

So I want to assign values while returning the correct token to the parser and without using the union so that I can use all C++ features.

Note: I saw [this example](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bison.git/tree/examples/c++/variant.yy) but I still can't understand are functions `make_Number` already exist or they are generated? How to add value to the $ variables which belong to a defined %token from my next_token() ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

`#define api.pure` only applies to parsers generated with the C API. If you ask bison to produce a C++ parser, you don't need that declaration because [it's unnecessary](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/C_002b_002b-Scanner-Interface.html#C_002b_002b-Scanner-Interface):

> The parser invokes the scanner by calling yylex. Contrary to C parsers, C++ parsers are always pure: there is no point in using the `%define api.pure` directive.

But the C++ API(s) are very different from the C API. If to want to use them, you really need to read that entire manual chapter (refer to the examples while you are reading.)

Note that the variant type created by Bison is very different from `std::variant`, so it might or might not be what you are looking for.  Unlike `std::variant`, Bison's variants do not store the current type of the variant's value, because the parser always knows the type of a stack value. That's fine while you're parsing, but it makes the variants less useful as exported values. (And in other applications as well.) However, they can help if you want to use non-trivial types like `std::string`, since Bison can ensure that destructors are correctly called. [Note 1]

If you're going to use smart pointers, you'll probably find yourself sprinkling calls to `std::move` in order to avoid copying non-copyable objects. (Objects on Bison's stack are often copied repeatedly during the parse.) You'll also want to use `std::move` to avoid excess copying of strings. You can request that Bison automatically insert calls to `std::move` on *every* access to a semantic value, but if you enable this option you need to take care to only use each semantic value once. (There's an example in the manual.)

Once you decide to use Bison's C++ API, you need to choose between two calling conventions for the lexical scanner. One option is what the manual calls ["split symbols"](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Split-Symbols), which is just the traditional C approach (modified as with the C pure API): the lexer returns an integer (the token type) and places the semantic value in an STYPE pointed to be the argument. If the STYPE is a Bison variant, you'll want to use the `emplace` method to construct a value in-place (thus avoiding a copy).

There are examples in the linked page of the Bison manual. It's a bit confusing that there are two examples of using `emplace`; my understanding is that the second example (in which `emplace` takes constructor arguments) is usable with C++11 or more recent, which these days should be pretty universal (IMHO).

Alternatively, you can use "complete symbols", which are described at more length and with more examples. If you tell Bison to use the "complete symbol" API (with the `%define api.token.constructor` declaration), then Bison will automatically generate the various `make_XXX` functions. To make use of these functions, you would have to change your scanner's `get_next_token` member function in order to return a `symbol_type` object instead of an `int` (and then it doesn't need a yylvalp argument). That might be a larger change than you want to make.

---

#### Notes:

1. You can use `std::variant` or the Boost equivalent with an explicit definition of `api.value.type` but that won't produce the `make_*` calls, and also Bison won't know how to extract individual types from the variant, so the whole `%type` mechanism won't work, making it not very attractive.

Comment: I read many things in the documentation and been trying for 3 days long but I didn't understand how to give bison the tokens and the values from my scanner ? it would be great if you give a more specified answer or a reading.

Comment: @MohamadZiadAlkabakibi: I added more information to the answer which  attempts to explain the options for providing tokens to the parser. It's not easy to provide specific code because I don't know what your specific needs are; there are examples in the manual (as I indicated). You need to understand that Bison is giving you several (mutually exclusive) options; you must decide which approach to take. Then you should try a small implementation of a part of your grammar to see if it works for you. If you run into specific issues, ask a more detailed question (as a new question).